# Dark mode in standalone Qt Designer on Windows?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, pyside2

I'm developing one GUI app (among others) in Python with PySide2 and my main editor is VSCode and I'd like to keep it this way - I'm using the standalone Qt Designer for GUI layout calling it from VSCode when necessary.

I see that the full Qt Creator has a way to select couple of different dark modes in its IDE settings, however I see no such possibility in the Qt Designer launched as standalone application.
I develop on Windows 10 by the way and setting its dark mode doesn't change how Qt Designer looks, it keeps its Windows Vista look:).

Is there something that can be done, maybe a command line parameter?

Comment: You can use a style sheet based on this code: [https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet) I use it in several of my Qt projects at work.

Comment: @drescherjm - thanks, this is certainly helpful for styling of the developed applications, but my question is about the theme of the Designer interface itself...

Comment: You probably have to modify the source code for designer  in the same manner you would to add a dark mode to your application.

Comment: On Linux I can set the style with command line parameter `-style`. Not sure if this works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @cges30901 I'll take a look at this.

Comment: @cges30901 what is the exact command line parameter are you using?

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication

Comment: @cges30901 this doc doesn't  say what are the values expected by -style flag in case of the Designer? What value do you pass to get the Dark mode?